# AutoFixture build collection with unique property

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

Is there any possibility to create a collection with a unique property in `AutoFixture`? For instance, I would like to create a collection of:

```
public class Foo {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

with unique `Id`. It would look something like this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();

fixture
 .Build<Foo>()
 .WithUnique((foo) => foo.Id)
 .CreateMany(20);
```

I know it is possible to do this through customization, but I think it's quite common scenario so might be `AutoFixture` has something ready for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Autofixture by default generates unique values for properties. So you don't have to specify which property should be unique - instead, specify a non-unique value for other property:

```
// with AutoFixture.SeedExtensions
fixture.Build<Foo>().With(f => f.Name, fixture.Create("Name")).CreateMany(20)
```

---

Note if you want to ensure non-unique values for other properties (having only Id unique), then you can create simple extensions for `IPostprocessComposer` which provide a set of possible values for the property:

```
public static IPostprocessComposer<T> With<T, TProperty>(
    this IPostprocessComposer<T> composer,
    Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker,
    IEnumerable<TProperty> possibleValues) =>
      composer.With(propertyPicker, possibleValues.ToArray());

public static IPostprocessComposer<T> With<T, TProperty>(
    this IPostprocessComposer<T> composer,
    Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker,
    params TProperty[] possibleValues)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    return composer.With(
       propertyPicker,
       () => possibleValues[rnd.Next(0, possibleValues.Length)]);
}
```

Usage is simple - following code creates list of foos with only two different values for name, and three different values for some integer property:

```
fixture.Build<Foo>()
    .With(f => f.SomeIntegerProperty, 10, 20, 50)
    .With(f => f.Name, fixture.CreateMany<string>(2))
    .CreateMany(20);
```

Comment: So it's always unique unless you exceed for instance 255 elements in the collection for `byte` type?

Comment: @OlegI yes, there is `RandomNumericSequencegenerator` used which *Creates a sequence of random, unique, numbers starting at 1.* (it just tracks list of random numbers in the range which already returned). After all numbers from range returned, history is cleared and generation starts from scratch

Comment: @OlegI you can check the numbers generation [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/RandomNumericSequenceGenerator.cs)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Actually, after the `byte` range is exceeded, the `RandomNumericSequenceGenerator` switches to the larger range, which doesn't include the previous range. Therefore, I'd say that numbers are always unique, if your property is of wide enough type (e.g. `short` or `int`).